# Is there a way to scale my dataset to [-1,1] interval per date?

Tags: r, date, scale, intervals

I currently have a dataset of 13 variables with 754 unique dates (March 1957 to December 2019). all dates appear a lot of times within the dataset (I have around 3 million observations). And I have to normalize all the variables to a [-1,1] scale by date. I tried using the following code but it normalizes the entire dataset and not by year. I tried looking for a solution but couldn't find any, so I hope you guys can help me.

```
normalize <- function(x) {
  return ((2*(x - min(x, na.rm = TRUE)) / (max(x, na.rm = TRUE) - min(x, na.rm = TRUE)))-1)}

Normalized_data <- Complete_data %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  as.data.frame(apply(Complete_data,2,normalize))
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply using mutate should work

```
Complete_data %>%
 group_by(Date) %>%
 mutate(normalized = normalize(Complete_data))
```

*Note that it is helpful if you provide a portion of your dataset (minimal example)*